# ¿Como obtengo el valor de un input numérico que fue creado mediante php y de forma dinámica?

Tags: php, html, jquery, table

Actualmente tengo una tabla donde se generan los td's de acuerdo a unas respectivas variables y dentro de un td se pone un `<input>` de tipo numérico, pero cuando a través de jquery quiero acceder a cada uno de los inputs de acuerdo a el que hagan click y a su vez ese valor multiplicarlo por un precio unitario para que me de un total sobre la misma fila, ese proceso me da como resultado siempre uno aunque el valor vaya aumentando.

código de JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#CartTable').on("click", 'tr', function(){
  var precioU=$(this)[0].cells[3].innerText;
  console.log($($(this)[0].cells[4].innerHTML).val());
  var celda=$(this)[0].cells[4].innerHTML;
});
```

Código de PHP:

```
while($row = $result_conn->fetch_assoc()) {
  $table.="<tr>";
  $table.="<td><a class='remove' href='#'><fa class='fa fa-close'></fa></a></td>".
  "<td><a href='#'><img src='img/man/polo-shirt-1.png' alt='img'></a></td>".
  "<td><a class='aa-cart-title' href='#'>".$row["NombreProducto"]."</a></td>".
  "<td>".$row["PrecioUnitario"]."</td>"."<td><input class='aa-cart-quantity'  attr_Input=".$i." type='number' value=1 ></td>"." <td>$250</td>";
  $table.="</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolverlo debes pensar en otro enfoque, lo que buscas es que al modificar el valor del `<input>` se cambien los demás valores en la tabla, por tanto es al `<input>` al que debes asignar la función.

El `<input>` tiene la clase `aa-cart-quantity`, asignas un evento, para que reciba, cualquier cambio es mejor `onchange`, luego para obtener la celda usas `parents('td')` para retroceder a la celda anterior usas `prev()` y para acceder a la siguiente usas `next()`.

El código funcionaria así:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.aa-cart-quantity').on("change", function(){
    var valor = this.value;
    var actual = $(this).parents('td');
    var precioU = actual.prev().text();
    $(actual).next().text('$'+precioU*valor);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table border="1"id="CartTable">

  <tr >
    <td><a class='remove' href='#'><fa class='fa fa-close'></fa></a></td>
    <td><a href='#'><img src='img/man/polo-shirt-1.png' alt='img'></a></td>
    <td><a class='aa-cart-title' href='#'>NombreProducto 1</a></td>
    <td>10</td><td><input class='aa-cart-quantity' min=0 attr_Input="2" type='number' value=1 max=1000 ></td> <td>$10</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td><a class='remove' href='#'><fa class='fa fa-close'></fa></a></td>
    <td><a href='#'><img src='img/man/polo-shirt-1.png' alt='img'></a></td>
    <td><a class='aa-cart-title' href='#'>NombreProducto 2</a></td>
    <td>250</td><td><input class='aa-cart-quantity' min=0 attr_Input="2" type='number' max=1000 value=1 ></td> <td>$250</td>
  </tr> 
</table>  

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Te recomiendo ponerle un mínimo y máximo al `<input>` así evitas problemas de negativos.

```
<input class='aa-cart-quantity' min=0 attr_Input="2" type='number' value=1 max=1000 >
```

Luego en el código PHP no tendrías por que hacer ningún cambio.

y así el código ya funciona como esperas, saludos.